# include error terms in linear regression model

Tags: r, linear-regression

I was wondering if there is a way to include error terms for a linear regression model like:

```
r = lm(y ~ x1+x2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by error terms? Your code will fit the following linear model:
y = a + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + e
where e is the error.

Comment: So the model already includes the error terms ? 

But I have seen this aswell :
y ~ A*B + Error(C)

Answer (score 6):

The code `r = lm(y ~ x1+x2)` means we model y as a linear function of x1 and x2.  Since the model will not be perfect, there will be a residual term (i.e. the left-over that the model failed to fit).

In maths, as Rob Hyndman noted in the comments, `y = a + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + e`, where `a`, `b1` and `b2` are constants and `e` is your residual (which is assumed to be normally distributed).

To look at a concrete example, consider the iris data that comes with R.

```
model1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=iris)
```

Now we can extract the constants from the model (equivalent to `a`, `b1`, `b2` and in this case `b3` too).

```
> coefficients(model1)
(Intercept)  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
1.8559975    0.6508372    0.7091320   -0.5564827
```

The residuals have been calculated for each row of data that was used in the model.

```
> residuals(model1)
           1             2             3             4             5       
0.0845842387  0.2100028184 -0.0492514176 -0.2259940935 -0.0804994772
# etc. There are 150 residuals and 150 rows in the iris dataset.
```

---

(EDIT: Cut summary info as not relevent.)

---

EDIT:

The `Error` value you mention in your comments in explained on the help page to aov.

```
If the formula contains a single ‘Error’ term, this is used to
specify error strata, and appropriate models are fitted within
each error stratum.
```

Compare the following (adapted from the `?aov` page.)

```
> utils::data(npk, package="MASS")
> aov(yield ~  N*P*K, npk)
Call:
   aov(formula = yield ~ N * P * K, data = npk)

Terms:
                       N        P        K      N:P      N:K      P:K    N:P:K Residuals
Sum of Squares  189.2817   8.4017  95.2017  21.2817  33.1350   0.4817  37.0017  491.5800
Deg. of Freedom        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        16

Residual standard error: 5.542901 
Estimated effects may be unbalanced

> aov(yield ~  N*P*K + Error(block), npk)
Call:
aov(formula = yield ~ N * P * K + Error(block), data = npk)

Grand Mean: 54.875 

Stratum 1: block

Terms:
                    N:P:K Residuals
Sum of Squares   37.00167 306.29333
Deg. of Freedom         1         4

Residual standard error: 8.750619 
Estimated effects are balanced

Stratum 2: Within

Terms:
                        N         P         K       N:P       N:K       P:K Residuals
Sum of Squares  189.28167   8.40167  95.20167  21.28167  33.13500   0.48167 185.28667
Deg. of Freedom         1         1         1         1         1         1        12

Residual standard error: 3.929447 
1 out of 7 effects not estimable
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

Comment: Hey Richie, this looks interesting . So I thought I may try this in R : 
> v = aov(yield ~  N*P*K, npk)
>v2 = aov(yield ~  N*P*K + Error(block), npk)

> coefficients(v)

> coefficients(v2)

What type of regression is this ? And  what are the  coefficients such as N1:P1 and N1:P1:K1 ?

Comment: @phpdash: This is sometimes known as split-plot ANOVA.  There's a step-by-step example in Statistical Computing by Michael Crawley.   http://books.google.com/books?id=OlPUa6lVeb0C&pg=PA345#