# evaluating contrasts for a split-plot design in R

Tags: r

I have data from a split-plot experiment, and I'd like to evaluate some contrasts between different factorial combinations. Evaluating contrasts of a complete randomized design, or a randomized complete block design seems straightforward: create an `lm()` object, construct a contrast matrix, then analyze contrasts with `glht()` from the `multcomp` package. However, I'm not aware of how to make an `lm()` object that takes into account the error terms needed for a split-plot analysis. I can make an `aov()` object that reflects the experiment design, but I'm unsure how to use that to evaluate contrasts. Below is a reprex with some example data. I feel an obvious answer must be out there, but my own searching has failed me. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)

structure(list(Treatment = c("on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on", 
"on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "al", "al", 
"al", "al", "al", "al", "al", "al", "al", "al", "al", "al", "al", 
"al", "al", "ix", "ix", "ix", "ix", "ix", "ix", "ix", "ix", "ix", 
"ix", "ix", "ix", "ix", "ix", "ix"), Material = c("T", "T", "T", 
"A", "A", "A", "E", "E", "E", "N", "N", "N", "O", "O", "O", "T", 
"T", "T", "A", "A", "A", "E", "E", "E", "N", "N", "N", "O", "O", 
"O", "T", "T", "T", "A", "A", "A", "E", "E", "E", "N", "N", "N", 
"O", "O", "O"), Rep = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), Measurement = c(20.67, 20.74, 
20.6, 14.35, 14.42, 14.39, 15.04, 15.08, 15, 18.08, 18.08, 18.14, 
18.61, 18.55, 18.08, 20.89, 20.89, 20.67, 14.46, 14.53, 14.39, 
15.12, 15.16, 15.04, 18.25, 18.31, 18.14, 18.61, 18.8, 18.55, 
20.74, 21.5, 20.89, 14.6, 14.53, 14.46, 15.4, 15.48, 15.16, 18.73, 
18.73, 18.31, 18.55, 19.17, 18.73)), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

spd.data$Treatment = as.factor(spd.data$Treatment)
spd.data$Material = as.factor(spd.data$Material)
spd.data$Rep = as.factor(spd.data$Rep)

spd.data.aov = spd.data %>%
  aov(Measurement~
        Rep +
        Treatment + 
        Error(Rep/Treatment) +
        Material + 
        Material:Treatment, .)

spd.data.aov %>% summary()

spd.data.lm = spd.data %>%
  lm(Measurement~
        Rep +
        Treatment + 
        Error(Rep/Treatment) +
        Material + 
        Material:Treatment, .)
```

The final `lm()` evaluation outputs `Error in Error(Rep/Treatment) : could not find function "Error"`. Also, apologies for not using a built-in dataset, but I couldn't find any that reasonably fit into a split-plot design.

Comment: I realized that I had rounded too many digits in my reprex data, so some reps were essentially identical. I corrected that, please let me know if that is not what you were asking for.

Comment: Does `Error` works with `lm`

Comment: For me it does not.

Comment: I meant in `aov` it is specifically written in documentaiton `If the formula contains a single Error term, this is used to specify error strata, and appropriate models are fitted within each error stratum.`

Comment: You may also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801487/include-error-terms-in-linear-regression-model)

Comment: It sounds like an `lm()` object is designed to have a single built-in error term, therefore I'm still unsure how to evaluate contrasts for a split-plot model that uses two error terms.